# Check if ObjectInputStream has anything to read without blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, inputstream

I am building a server in java that communicates with several clients at the same time, the initial approach we had is the the server listens to connections from the clients, once a connection is received and a socket is created, a new thread is spawned to handle the communication with each client, that is read the request with an  ObjectInputStream, do the desired operation (fetch data from the DB, update it, etc.), and send back a response to the client (if needed). While the server itself goes back to listen to more connections.

This works fine for the time being, however this approach is not really scalable, it works great for a small amount of clients connected at the same time, however since every client spawns another thread, what will happen when there are a too many clients connected at once?

So my next idea was to maintain a list of sorts that will hold all connected clients (the socket object and some extra info), use a ThreadPool for to iterate through them and read anything they sent, if a message was received then put it in a queue for execution by another ThreadPool of worker threads, and once the worker has finished with its task if a response is required then send it.

The 2 latter steps are pretty trivial to implement, the problem is that with the original thread per client implementation, I use ObjectInputStream.readObject() to read the message, and this method blocks until there is something to read, which is fine for this approach, but I can't use the same thing for the new approach, since if I block on every socket, I will never get to the ones that are further down the list.

So I need a way to check if I have anything to read before I call readObject(), so far I tried the following solutions:

**Solution 1:**
use ObjectInputStream.available() to check if there is anything available to read, this approach failed since this method seems to always return 0, regardless of whether there is an object in the stream or not. So this does not help at all.

**Solution 2:**
Use PushbackInputStream to check for the existence of the first unread byte in the stream, if it exists then push it back and read the object using the ObjectInputStream, and if it doesn't move on:

```
            boolean available;
            int b = pushbackinput.read();
            if (b==-1)
                  available = false;
            else
            {
                pushbackinput.unread(b);
                available = true;
            }
            if (available)
            {
            Object message= objectinput.readObject();
            // continue with what you need to do with that object
            }
```

This turned out to be useless too, since read() blocks also if there is no input to read. It seems to only return the -1 option if the stream was closed. If the stream is still open but empty it just blocks, so this is no different than simply using ObjectInputStream.readObject();

Can anyone suggest an approach that will actually work?

Comment: ObjectInputStream is designed for blocking IO.  The problem you have is that even if some data is available you don't know how bytes will be needed to read the next object. i.e. what is a useful amount.  I would create a thread per connection and you don't need to create your own threading model.

Comment: You might want to consider switching to NIO channels which support read methods that return `Future` and the like.

Comment: Blocking I/O with a thread per connection scales to tens if not hundreds of thousands of concurrent clients.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and you've done some homework.... but it involves going through some history to get things right. Note, your issue is actually more to do with the socket-level communication rather than the ObjectInputStream:

The easiest way to do things in the past was to have a separate thread per socket. This was scalable to a point but threads were expensive and slow to create.

In response, for large systems, people created thread pools and would service the sockets on threads when there was work to do. This was complicated.

The Java language was then changed with the java.nio package which introduced the [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) together with non-blocking IO. This created a reliable (although sometimes confusing) way to service multiple sockets with fewer threads. In your case through, it would not help fully/much because you want to know when a full Object is ready to be read, not when there's just 'some' object.

In the interim the 'landscape' changed, and Java is now able to more efficiently create and manage threads. 'Current' thinking is that it is better/faster and easier to allocate a single thread per socket again.... see [Java thread per connection model vs NIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752130/java-thread-per-connection-model-vs-nio)

In your case, I would suggest that you stick with the thread-per-socket model, and you'll be fine. Java can scale and handle more threads than sockets, so you'll be fine.

Comment: Do you know how to create  ObjectInputStream over NIO channel?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481639/java-serializable-objectinputstream-non-blocking-i-o and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862971/java-readobject-with-nio ?